# How to Find Checkbox within Asp.net panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I cannot find the checkboxes within Panel. Here is my code.  On page load I add dynamically controls. It loads all controls properly:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack){
foreach (var chk in chks)
{
   PlSettings.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"Controls\">"));

   PlSettings.Controls.Add(chk);

   PlSettings.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
}
}
```

On button update, I would like to loop through all controls within panel, and if type of checbox, check if it's checked or not.

```
foreach (var panelctrl in PlSettings.Controls)
            {

                  if (panelctrl.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
                   {
                      var checkbox = (CheckBox)chk;

                      if (checkbox.Checked)
                       {
                                userSettings.Add(Convert.ToInt32(checkbox.ID));
                       }
                   }

            }
```

For some reason Panel has only one literal control. and no controls within.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the foreach with this code:

```
// if(!Page.IsPostBack){
foreach (var chk in chks)
{
   PlSettings.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"Controls\">"));

   PlSettings.Controls.Add(chk);

   PlSettings.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
}
//}
```

You must add dynamic controls on every postback.  Also, make sure this is done during init or preinit stage.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```
foreach (CheckBox chk in PlSettings.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    //code here
}
```

And since these controls are being generated dynamically, you'll need to recreate the controls at every postback. Make sure you assign the same ID to the controls each time too, so that ViewState can reload the checked state.